# Not able to get user given name and surname using UseOpenId Connect Authentication

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dotnetopenauth, openid-connect

I have configure the app for using open Id :

```
 app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
            {
                ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAD:ClientId"],
                Authority = String.Format(Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:AadInstance"], Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:Tenant"]),
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
                SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,

                // PostLogoutRedirectUri = Configuration["AzureAd:PostLogoutRedirectUri"],
                Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                {
                    OnRemoteFailure = OnAuthenticationFailed                      

                }
            });
```

**and using claimtype constants to get the surname value, but value is null**

```
 public static string GetUserName(System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal userObj, IRetrieveUow _Uow)
    {
        if (userObj.Identity == null || userObj.Identity.Name == null)
        {
            return "Guest Login";
        }
        else
        {
            var user = _Uow.Users.GetAll().Where(f => f.UserName == userObj.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();


            var s= userObj.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname").Value;
```

**But the value of variable s is null.**

Comment: Your code to get surname is in the controller ? and please confirm that azure ad user has first name/last name properties in azure ad user profile blade .

Comment: yeah using claimtype, i want to extract that info. Yes azure ad has that information.

Comment: It works on my side with` User.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname").Value;` ,  apart from azure ad account , does you app also enable individual account login ?

Comment: Yes it azure AD login using open id connect

Comment: So you use asp.net identity for local user login and openid connect for azure ad login ?

Comment: nope azure AD authentication only

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem , if possible , could you please share us your test project ?